# Include request parameters in URL when using Postman

Tags: api, postman

I need to fire some requests using Postman but I need to include the parameter in the URL.

What I need:
https://serveraddress/v1/busride/user/favorites/route/RanDOMid

What I currently can configure in Postman:
https://serveraddress/v1/busride/user/favorites/route/?id=RanDOMid

I do not control the server, so I need to work it out how to craft the request in Postman to accept the input data as part of the URL, not as parameter. How can I specify input data in Postman to get it included in URL?

Answer (score 0):

Click on Manage Environment

Add variable as path with Initial and current value as `RanDOMid`

Add path to URL:

```
https://serveraddress/v1/busride/user/favorites/route/{{path}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@User7294900's answer should do for you in case all you want to do is include a variable in your request URL.

However, if you want to actually generate a random ID for every request, you may use {{$guid}} or {{$randomInt}} directly in you URL as follows:

```
 https://serveraddress/v1/busride/user/favorites/route/{{$guid}}
```

This will generate a random GUID every time your request is fired and the generated GUID will replace {{$guid}} in your URL.

or

```
https://serveraddress/v1/busride/user/favorites/route/{{$randomInt}}
```

This will generate a random integer between 0 and 1000 every time your request is fired and the generated integer will replace {{$randomInt}} in your URL.

Refer postman documentation for more details - https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

Hope this helps!